# how to clean variable or function after use

Tags: ios

I am so sorry in advance if my question is such a stupid question.
I tried to make an app with lack of programming foundation knowledge. 
I applied this function from somebody in stackoverflow forum. then I edited it a bit.

```
-(void)computeDistanceFrom:(CLLocation *)oldL tO:(CLLocation *)newL {

    NSLog(@"oldL %@",oldL);
    NSLog(@"newL %@",newL);

    CLLocationDistance currentDistance = [oldL distanceFromLocation:newL];
    NSLog(@"you have travel=%f",currentDistance);   
    distance = distance + currentDistance;

     distanceInKm = distance/1000;
     carbonSaveKg = distanceInKm*0.069565217;
     fuelSaveLit  = distanceInKm*0.073913043;

    //set string to show
    distanceLabelValue = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.3f",distanceInKm]retain];
    distanceLabel.text = distanceLabelValue;
    NSLog(@"distanceFromView=%f",distanceInKm); 

    carbonDioxideLabelValue = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.3f",carbonSaveKg]retain];
    carbonDioxideLabel.text = carbonDioxideLabelValue;
    NSLog(@"CO2FromView=%f",carbonSaveKg); 

    fuelLabelValue = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",fuelSaveLit]retain];
    fuelLabel.text = fuelLabelValue;
    NSLog(@"FuelFromView=%f",fuelSaveLit); 

    }
```

My app tracks a current position of user. Then it displays distance and a couple of values by labels. When I leave the view where it contains this function, I want to set the values of the variables `distanceInKm`,`carbonSaveKG` and `fuelLit` to 0.

My problem is when I go back to this view again, the value of the variables is still as they existed before.
Please help me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this method and call it before you go back to this view.

```
- (void)clearLabels {
    distanceLabel.text = @"";
    carbonDioxideLabel.text = @"";
    fuelLabel.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Matic. I tried the function and it seemed like the function just cleared label but didn't clean variable which keeps the value. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand what you really want to do.. You could also call distanceLabelValue = @"" and distanceInKm = 0 for all values. But also know there might be memory leaks with this code since your strings are retained, be sure to call release on them before you assign them another value.

Comment: I was so curious about these objects. At first, I did not retain them and compiler returned memory leak issue 'BAD_EXC_ACCESS'. After I retained them, the error had gone. :( More, I have already tried distanceInKm = 0; but the result was still be the same. I guessed that perhaps because of retaining, so the variable still keep containing value.

Comment: Well, that is another topic.. Could you explain your problem a bit better? When does this method of yours get called? And what are you trying to do? It might seem from your post you are trying to track some distance and reset it to zero at some point. In that case you only have to call "distance = 0;"